# Php.ini strftime() not safe Mac osx mavericks

Tags: php, macos

I'm getting an error whilst using php + smarty on my mac running mavericks.

I've read in several places that you must change the timezone settings in the php.ini files.

i've also run the command to see which file php is pointing to:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

After that i changed the date.timezone line to the following...

```
date.timezone = "Australia/Sydney"
```

and this was done in the files

/etc/php.ini
/etc/php.ini-5.2-previous
/etc/php.ini.default

The error is as follows...

```
Warning: strftime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. 
You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. 
In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. 
We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.
timezone to select your timezone. 
in /Library/Smarty3.1.16/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 234
```

Comment: The `php` on the CLI and the PHP in your web server may be different.

Comment: I'm using the server that's provided by apple. It's an apache2 webserver.

Comment: what i mean is, i'm not using something like XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still wondering.

Similarly, in my case, Yosemite OS, I had no php.ini file in /etc. So I copied /etc/php.ini.default and modified it by adding a timezone and removing ;

```
$ sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

And then:

```
date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```